# What is $T'(A)$, where $T'$ denotes the adjoint of the mapping $T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, duality-theorems

Let  $ V = M_n(C)$ be equipped with the inner-product $(A,B) = tr(B_xA)$, $A,B ∈ V$ and $B_x$ is transpose of $B$. Let $M ∈M_n(C)$. Deﬁne $T : V → V$ by $T(A) = MA$. What is $T'(A)$, where $T'$ denotes the adjoint of the mapping $T$ ?
we can say by the condition  $(T(A), B) = (A, T'(B))$ this implies $tr(B_xMA) = tr((T'(B))_xA)$

from here Can I conclude something?

Comment: The naive answer seems to be that $(T'(B))_x$ should be $B_xM$, so maybe $T'(B) = M_x B$?

Comment: yeaa..U are correct..But how?

Comment: As you pointed out, you should have $\mathrm{tr}(B_xMA) = \mathrm{tr}(T'(B)_xA)$, and this will be true if $T'(B)_x = B_xM$. Now just take transpose of both sides and use that $(XY)_x = Y_xX_x$ in general.

Comment: $why??T′(B)_x=B_xM$

Comment: Just look at your equation, which you've already said above: $\mathrm{tr}(B_xMA) = \mathrm{tr}(T'(B)_xA)$. Bot sides are the trace of SOMETHING times $A$. I'm just setting the two SOMETHING's equal to each other.

Comment: so u r saying if Tr(AB) = 0 then A = 0?  Is it possible? U can construct easily one counter example in a second..

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm saying, and I don't see how what I said implies that. I'm not saying that $A=C$ is a necessary condition for $\mathrm{tr}(AB) = \mathrm{tr}(CB)$. I'm saying it's a SUFFICIENT condition.

Comment: It has to be NECESSARY to reach the conclusion..

Comment: Isn't the dual/transpose map unique, though? So since this satisfies the defining property of the transpose of $T$, it must be the transpose of $T$.